# Which is the best choice? You must try to run ( ) as you can on the limited food and water that you have

Tags: word-choice

> You must try to run ( ) as you can on the limited food and water that you have.
>
> a) as wide
>   b) as long
>   c) as far
>   d) as possible

I deem b.c.d are all right. Which is the best one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure the person who wrote the test wants you to give "C". In this position, an adverb is needed.

It is possible to "run wide", in the context of, for example, football. It means "Run along the edge of the pitch". It doesn't make much sense when combined with "on limited food"

You can talk about "a long run" (adjective), or "run for a long time".  You could say "run for as long as you can" to mean "for a long time". You could even omit the word "for". So (b) is possible, but unlikely. In a test situation, you would not be dropping the word "for".

(c) is most likely. It refers to distance. The word "far" can act as an adverb without "for" or another proposition.

(d) doesn't make sense. You can't "run possible" because "possible" isn't an adverb. Moreover "as possible as you can" doesn't have a clear meaning.

Comment: Can you tell me why (d)  doesn't  make sense. I once saw ' as possible as you can'.

Comment: Where did you see that? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Okay, I think I remember wrongly. Thanks.

Comment: James, are you sure "possible" is not an adverb. Merraim U lists "possible" as an adverb although it is labeled as "archaic".

Comment: And it redirects to **the adverb "possibly"**. Sounds very silly but to me, but to me may be only could make sense.

Comment: And I am afraid I don't understand the clear difference between long and far in this context. The "long" is a clear adverb and seems to me, even though a non native speaker, has no big difference from "far" in this context.